# Script to copy data between sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I'm trying to create a script to copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and at the same time reorder it. I get my data from a Google form, so data is constantly updating.

Here are two images as examples. N°1 is how I have my data, N°2 is how I want it to be in sheet 2.

The idea is to have the script copying the data every time a new row appears.

Data from Forms.

[image: Data from Form]

This is how I would like it to be.

[image: This is how I would like it to be]

This is my initial code:

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ingreso'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('J:J');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Auxiliar Ingreso'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var columnasfijas = [];
  var cadena = [];


  //Condition check in G:G; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=1; i<testvalue.length;i++) {

  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues());

  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Si') {
   data = (sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues()).concat  (sheet.getRange(i+1,11,1,9).getValues()); // this beaks up into 2 rows Idon't know why
   /*cadena = (columnasfijas);
   data.push.apply(data, columnasfijas);*/
 }

  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 //csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

In this line, I'm also having trouble concatenating different lengths of data. It should be: `(i+1,1,1,6). concat.....(i+1,11,1,3)`

`data = (sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues()).concat  (sheet.getRange(i+1,11,1,9).getValues()); // this beaks up into 2 rows Idon't know why`

When I run it as it should by I receive an error that the length should be 9 instead of 3.

Comment: Can you provide your current script? It will help users think of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished more simply using formulas instead of app scripts:

```
=sort(importrange("spreadsheetURL", "Sheet1!A2:AA10000"),sort_col#,TRUE/FALSE,[sort_col2#],[TRUE/FALSE]...)
```

Documentation on importrange function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340
Documentation on sort function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150

Once you input the formula, there will likely red triangle on the cell, be sure to click on the cell and click the Allow Access button to give one spreadsheet access to the other.

Comment: Thaks Ross, but the formula mentioned doesn't do the required.