# Google Script: Moving row to different sheets based on multiple conditions

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a spreadsheet that I'd like to separate based on the data found in one particular cell. The main spreadsheet has a column that indicates either "tardy, discipline, reinforcement." I'd like to move "tardy" and "reinforcement" into their own spreadsheets. Additionally, I'd like "tardy" and "reinforcement" lines to be removed, once in the appropriate sheet. This should give me a total of three spreadsheets.

I've used a script before that was working and moving my tardy lines onto a different spreadsheet. However, for whatever reason, I am not getting an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 19, file "Code").

I've been playing around with this and it's likely I've messed something up. I have no experience coding but I'm trying my best to figure this out. Currently, the script I have is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Minor Infractions - Current'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('O:O'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Tardies - Current'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in O:O; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Tardy') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet
 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); 

//Delete matched rows in the source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that if an answer fixes your problem, or is most helpful to your success, you can click the green check mark to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

as [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181543/script-to-copy-data-between-sheets), you could accomplish this with a function:

```
=sort(importrange("spreadsheetURL", "Sheet1!A2:AA10000"),sort_col#,TRUE/FALSE,[sort_col2#],[TRUE/FALSE]...)
```

keep in mind this function is a guide, you can't just copy and paste, you have to fill out the values

Comment: Could you give an example on how to edit this? In particular, how would I move the lines from the original sheet to a different sheet?

Comment: you need to replace the `"spreadsheetURL"` with the spreadsheetURL. `sort_col#` with the column number from the first sheet, `sort_col2#` with the column number from the second sheet. `TRUE/FALSE` and `[TRUE/FALSE]` with true or false

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyrange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Minor Infractions - Current');
  const testrange=sheet.getRange(1,15,sheet.getLastRow()); 
  const testvalue=testrange.getValues();
  const csh=ss.getSheetByName('Tardies - Current');
  let data=[];
  let d=0;
  for (let i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i]=='Tardy') {
      data.push(sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValue());
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  }
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); 
}
```

Comment: How could I use this script to move rows from the original document to a sheet for tardies, and then move rows from the original document that are reinforcement, to reinforecement?

Comment: That’s too broad of a question

Comment: I have more details in my original post, I think. I'm not even sure how to ask the question because I don't really know what I'm doing :(